# Алгоритм проверки равенства элементов

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Добрый день, я новичек на плюсах.

Имеется *list* на с++

Не могу осилить алгоритм проверки равенства элементов на нечетных позициях.

К примеру: проверка **A**Z**A**Z**A**Z и **A**N**A**H**A**Q, вернет 1(true);

```
bool сompare(char a, char b)
{
??
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если Вам нужен аналог сравнения строк только для нечетных элементов (какой-то изврат с русским в UTF-8 ?), то так и напишите в вопросе.

Четность двух абстрактных символов можно только угалывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компаратору нужно знать еще и индекс проверяемого элемента для того, чтоб он мог "решить", проверять элемент или нет.

псевдокод:

```
struct comparator {
   comparator(int &idx)
      :idx(idx)
   {}

   bool operator()(char left, char right) const {
      return ((idx & 1) ? left==right : false);
   }

private:
   int &idx;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Если без использования STL, то просто пишем цикл, в котором  индекс проверяемых элементов меняется с каждой итерацией с шагом 2.

Если нужно строго применять STL, то, мне кажется, лучше обратить внимание не на компаратор, а написать свой итератор, который бы "шагал" только по четным элементам контейнера.